# Dynamic Integration flow Registration causing performance degradation

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

For example, we have a **sample flow which has 20 different beans** and we are registering them
dynamically using `IntegrationFlowRegistrationBuilder#register()` method.

- Registration time is degrading once we register at least **200 flows of same type parallelly**.
  Initially, bean registration takes 10 seconds which is fine but after registering certain amount of flows,
  time is significantly increases and at last it is 26 minutes which is too high.

  **Note: Every flow has different bean configurations and they are not similar in any way so
  that reusability of same bean is not possible.**

I would like to understand the cause behind it.

Comment: Confirm, please, what Spring Integration version do you use?

Comment: we are using 5.5.0 version

Answer (score 0):

The performance is degrading just because you give more and more beans for the application context on each flow registration. And each new flow needs to recheck existing beans to avoid duplication error, so we will try to reuse as much beans as possible.

I understand your concern about different beans and redundant scanning procedure, but how can we know that on the bean registration that this is new object or you try to inject an existing one?

To improve some parallel registration performance, consider to set a unique id for those dynamic flows. See its builder API:

```
    /**
     * Specify an {@code id} for the {@link IntegrationFlow} to register.
     * Must be unique per context.
     * The registration with this {@code id} must be destroyed before reusing for
     * a new {@link IntegrationFlow} instance.
     * @param id the id for the {@link IntegrationFlow} to register
     * @return the current builder instance
     */
    IntegrationFlowRegistrationBuilder id(String id);
```

This way the lock is not used to synchronize on bean registrations and they can be created concurrently.

**UPDATE**

I looked into the code and probably a culprit is here:

```
return !this.beanFactory.getBeansOfType(instance.getClass(), false, false)
            .values()
            .contains(instance);
```

On every bean you trying to add which is not a `NamedComponent` or comes without a `beanName`. Consider to add explicit `id` to all the endpoints you declare in your flows. Something like this:

```
.<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase, e -> e.id(flowId + ".transformer"))
```

I'm thinking about possible optimization for this kind of registrations when we add an implicit bean names to those unnamed components...

Please, raise a GitHub issue and we will think together what and how could be improved: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues

Comment: We have already provided unique flow ids.

Comment: Ok. Any chances to have some project from you to investigate ?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have raised GH issue for this.

Comment: The GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3653